# Robot Framework (RIDE): Data Sanity Check failing

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

I am getting below error when I copy this value in my `RIDE` resource file in Robot Framework. Don't know what is wrong with this value.

I am able to save other 900 values in same format but not this one.

> ERROR:Data Sanity Check Failed.Reset Changes?

Value I am trying to save is as below:

```
${MISDOB2ATTMM}  Dobson to VF Migration (Manual)
```

Examples of correct values:

```
${CHILE}    Chile 
${CI}    Cote d Ivoire (Ivory Coast) 
${CN}    China, Peoples Republic of 
${COSTARICA}    Costa recei
```

Comment: Show another line which is ok.

Comment: few values are as below   ${CHILE}          Chile
${CI}             Cote d Ivoire (Ivory Coast)
${CN}             China, Peoples Republic of
${COSTARICA}      Costa recei

Comment: Add them to the question properly formatted. It's mot readable in comments.

Comment: ahh, the error does not have the details of actual failure, it looks like a high level error message. are you sure it is failed because of this assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you got was from the Text Editor (you did not mention this).
This could be because there may be invisible characters in that variable definition. Maybe indentation, or even a TAB symbol.

Also, that format for variable definition is correct for the section,

```
*** Variables ***
```

But not correct for keywords or test case sections.
I recommend to always use the '=' symbol for variables assignments outside the Variables section. For example:

```
${MISDOB2ATTMM}=    Set Variable    Dobson to VF Migration (Manual)
```

Comment: Yes I am trying to save in variable section only.
But how do i find for any inivisible character or TAB symbol?Cant find any difference when i copy that to normal text file too.

Comment: Try to set the variable using the New Scalar button, instead of using the Text Editor.
Try to type all the text, instead of pasting.
(I just have copy and pasted from your question, and it worked).

Comment: Basically I am copying file from server with all the values and making resource file.Found one difference between values which I am able to save and one which i am not able to save.Copied in word document and enabled all hidden formatting marks.The difference I found between two values is one value has degree sign(for which I am getting error)and the other one does not have that degree sign.

Do you think this can be the cause?

Comment: I am able to figure out now.It is due to that special character I am not able to save that value.Thanks for help